# Not fetching from endpoint after page refreshes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

When i click on the document, the data successfully fetches from, however when i go to the same page and do a refresh then click on the document fetch is no longer happening ( i have inspect it in the browser ). What could be the reason for such a behavior?

this is my componentDidMount

```
@inject('selectedDocsStore')
@observer
class GeneralDocPresenter extends React.Component {

    state = {
        metaInfoDocs: [],
        docs: [],
        loading: false
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.selectedDocsStore.clear();
        this.props.selectedDocsStore.setViewDocId(0);
        this.setState({loading: true});
        this.props.fetchMetaDocs()
            .then((r) => this.setState({metaInfoDocs: r.data, loading: false}))
            .catch(err => {
                this.setState({loading: false});
                errorWithMessage('Could not load documents');
            });
        this.props.eventManager.on('viewDoc', (doc) => {
            this.loadDocuments(doc.id);
        })
    }


    render() {
        return <Translation>
            {(t) => {
                if (this.state.loading) {
                    return (
                        <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                            <Spin size={"medium"}/>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
                if (this.state.metaInfoDocs.length === 0) {
                    return (
                        <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                            <NoDocumentsAlert><div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: t('noDocuments')}}/></NoDocumentsAlert>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
                return (
                    <DocViewWrapper docs={this.state.docs}
                                    metaInfoDocs={this.state.metaInfoDocs.map(doc => {
                                        return {...doc, type: this.props.type}
                                    })}
                                    eventManager={this.props.eventManager}
                                    settings={this.props.settings}
                                    childComponents={this.props.childComponents}
                    />
                )
            }}
        </Translation>
    }

    loadDocuments(id) {
        this.props.loadDocument(id).then(r => {
            this.setState({
                docs: r.data
            })
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @SamimHakimi updated

Comment: sadly no that is not the case

Comment: I suggest isolating your code down to the core issue. IMO you may be pushing many answers away by doing too many things not core to your question.